# Is there an idiomatic way of versioning clients to a database?

Tags: cassandra, schema, database-schema, database-migration, cassandra-3.0

I'm supplying client drivers to a database I am maintaining. The DB has lots of tables with well defined schemas. (Cassandra in this case)

From time to time there will be some breaking changes (stemming from product and system requirements) and the clients will "break" in the sense that the queries they were performing until now will not be correct in regards to the newer schemas.

I'm curious to know if there is a good clean way to "version" the clients to work with the corresponding tables?

For instance a naive implementation could add the version number to the table name, i.e. for every table in the db , append a version number to the table name.

The clients would always query tables that match this naming convention. Newer breaking versions would change the table name to match the newer version and clients would be upgraded accordingly.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to add 1 version for you DB and 1 version that is stored on your client, when a breaking change is made you update the database version.
When the client starts a version check is performed and if the version missmatches an auto upgrade can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem few months ago. We have to load the schema according to the Version in which our client should support. The solution we found is as follows:

Along with the schema, one more table will be created which contains the following fields ---> version_no, ks_name, table_name, column_name, add/drop, is_loaded, primary key(version_no,(ks_name, table_name, column_name)). Note:if you have single keyspace, you can remove that column or table name can be itself written as ks_name.table_name.

Then, whenever we want to load a new version, we will log the changes in that table and when we load the previous schema again, the script will make sure that the old alterations are effected such that it will roll back to the same previous version of schema. Make sure that you update the is_loaded field as it is the only way to differentiate if a schema is half loaded or script failed such that it will not rise further more errors. Hope it helps!!